# Win 7, 64 bit, missing qt5widgets.dll

Tags: dll, qt5

I'm on windows 7 64bit, trying to run some software and I am getting an error indicating that I am missing `qt5widgets.dll`. I tried to find this dll from different websites but didn't have any luck. Where can I find the files to resolve this dependency ?

Comment: I presume that the software that needs the library didn't came bundled with it. Try redownloading and reinstalling the whole thing... it might work

Answer (score 1):

You would expect the required dll's would come bundled with the application. This application is a QT application and the aforementioned dll's can also be found at QT5 [official website](http://qt-project.org/downloads).

Answer (score 1):

You should contact the person who gave you the application.  The necessary libraries should have been included in the distribution.

Failing that, you may want to try [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads) you will need to get the version that the application is expecting, and potentially match the compiler that was used to build the application.